Is it not working to use NEXT.js as SSR webapp and call session authenticated web api?
I'm building a SSR next webapp and try to interact with a session authenticate express api.
Because I'm sending post request from the client side therefore I can have the sessionid and saved in the client side cookie.
When I try to do a server side fetching from the api, I found out that I can't get my session storage in the api with my cookie's sessionid, and a new session is save in store everytime I fetch from the api at server side.
Is it a wrong approach to make a SSR session authenticate application?
